# Android build fail in eclipse with a dx error when exporting maven dependencies

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

### Run with command line works !

In command line `mvn install android:deploy android:run` works fine.

### Run with Eclipse fails with dx error

I try to run my application with eclipse `run as > Android Application`

Then, it always fails with error

> [2013-09-10 00:19:51 - facets-mvn-integ-test] Dx 
>   trouble processing "javax/xml/namespace/QName.class":

### My Eclipse configuration

I use the following pugin :

**maven 3.0.4**

---

https://i.stack.imgur.com/afZnG.png

(same binary I use in command line - but It also fails with eclipse embedded one)

**m2e 1.4.0  & android configurator for m2e 0.4.2**

---

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz9Qk.png

### It works in Eclipse when I use private libraries instead of maven ...

If I dot not export Maven Dependencies I dot not have any dx error but I obvously have ClassNotFoundException

Weird fact is that when I dot not export maven libraries but I put the exact same jar un lib folder such as the libraries are exported with Andrdoid private libarries, it works fine.

Sadly, this is an acceptable solution.

### It works in Eclipse when I remove the android dependency ...

I'll be digging but I could not find any solution : I read somewhere to remove android dependency from pom. And it works in Eclipse ! But obviously, it does not work anymore with command line.

Here is my actual pom dependecies conf

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

So if anybody has faced this problem any help will be really appreciated ..

Comment: Note : I noticed that the bin and the target folder are different after an Eclipse or a maven commmand line build. - In the first case the target is empty but bin has a folder called dexedLibs with all my libs. - In the 2nd case target is not empty and as a classes.dex file. I guess because dx ended with success

Comment: It looks as though your JDom dependency is pulling classes in the restricted javax.xml package. Do you have any more errors appearing in your logs, for example a full stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be the way you are running the app from Eclipse. Try defining a Run or Debug Configuration under Maven Build with Goals: clean install android:deploy android:run

Also, set Base directory to the location of your pom.

Comment: Thx @Dave. What you propose is using maven in eclipse the way I maven use in with command line. It means I would not use m2e-android connector. But I would really like maven to be fully integrated in Eclipse. Your solution might be my fall back ...

Comment: Where are you getting that information? I don't think Android m2e alters the Android run configurations. If I try to run a Maven Android project with Run As > Android Application, I get Dex Loader errors. It never runs any Maven commands, and so the build is entirely hosed. I think you have to use the Maven Build configurations to leverage m2e. It is *somewhat* like using Maven from the command line, but I've still had issues even when a command line build works.

Comment: I am aware of what it is and who made it. I am asking why you think it is supposed to affect the debug/run configurations. I have seen no mention of that, nor do I think it makes sense. How would one plugin alter the GUI callbacks of another plugin? Even if that's possible, it would be a terrible practice.